# Scrapy CSS Selector ignore tags and get text only

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I have the following HTML :

```
<li class="last">
    <span>SKU:</span> 483151
</li>
```

I was able to select them using :

```
SKU_SELECTOR = '.aaa .bbb .last ::text'
sku = response.css(SKU_SELECTOR).extract_first().strip()
```

How can I get the number only and ignore the span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css selector has unnecessary space before `::text`.

```
SKU_SELECTOR = '.aaa .bbb .last ::text'
                               ^
```

Space indicates that any decendant-or-self node qualifies for this selector where you want to select only text under self.

I got it working:

```
>[0]: s = Selector(tex='...')
>[1]: s.css('.last::text').extract()
<[1]: [u'\n    ', u' 483151\n']
```