# Retrieve text from a span class using Scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I have been trying to extract text from a webpage using Scrapy. This is the HTML code:

```
<button type="submit" class="inlineBlock _2tga _49ve" title="Like Please" type="submit">
  <div class>
    <span class="_3jn- inlineBlock">...</span>
    <span class="_49vh _2pi7">Like</span>
    <span class="_5n6h _2pih" id="u_0_3">281</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

**EDIT**:

```
<button class="inlineBlock _2tga _49ve" id="u_0_2" title="Like Please" type="submit">
  <div class>
    <span class="_3jn- inlineBlock">...</span>
    <span class="_49vh _2pi7">Like</span>
    <span class="_5n6h _2pih" id="u_0_3">281</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

I want to extract the number `281`. To do this, I tried:

```
response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'_5n6h _2pih')]/descendant::text()")
```

And got:

```
[]
```

Also tried:

```
response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'_5n6h _2pih')]/span[contains(@class, 'u_0_3')]/descendant::text()")
```

And got, again:

```
[]
```

Comment: I tested your first XPath expression and it works as expected, so I cannot reproduce the error. Except that your `<button...>` is invalid, because it contains two `type="submit"` attributes.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I've corrected it.

Comment: Another error is the `<div class>`. The attribute should have a value like `<div class="xyz">`. This is another potential source of misbehaviour. However, after correcting the error I still get `281` as the result, so the XPath expression still seems correct to me.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260041/scrapy-css-selector-ignore-tags-and-get-text-only) answer.